# Plotting a scatter over a dataset

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot, scatter

I have a dataset from which I intent to make a scatterplot. It consists of 2 columns, where the first column should be used as x, and the other as y, so that each dot = x[0 firstcolumn], x[0 secondcolumn].

However I keep getting "x and y must be same size", and I cannot make out how to plot this. Below is my latest attempt on making them the same size, however unsuccesful

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = numpy.loadtxt('data')
x = range(len(X))
plt.scatter(x,X, color='blue', label = "car")
plt.show()
```

Comment: I've found that answer aswell, however when i try this i get the error "x and y must be the same size"

Comment: So you think there are magicians around here, which can just by looking at the code magically know the dataset you feed in? See [mcve].

Comment: What I meant is of course `plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1])`.

Comment: No i'm sorry, i simply assumed it was a simple problem which i was too stupid to see the solution of. The dataset consist of 150 inputs in first column, and 150 inputs in second column, both consisting of various numbers

Comment: I feel more stupid now... thx for the help ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: Sorry to bother u further, however if i then were to iterate through each element and do something, how would i do that? for example if i wanted the 53th element of both columns?

Comment: You get the 53th row of an array via `X[52,:]` (as indexing starts at zero).

Comment: so if i wanted the 53th element of the first row i would write X[52,:,0]?

Comment: No, unless you have a 3D array. Here it seems you have a 2D array which has N rows and 2 columns, you can hence only select the first or second element from that row, e.g. `X[0,1]` for the second element of the first row.